# Java Dependency Bad Gateway 502 - fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin 1.0.1 is missing

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies, vaadin

Inherited a project and am trying to run the build.gradle but the dependency is no long on maven... and I have googled and can't find any other active repos. There's a vaadin-spring 1.0.1 but I don't know if that's the same thing. Any body else run into this issue?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE")
        classpath('fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin:fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin.gradle.plugin:1.0.1')

    }
}

apply plugin: "fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin"
```

**The error:**

```
Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/johndevs/maven/fi/jasoft/plugin/gradle-vaadin-plugin/1.0.1/gradle-vaadin-plugin-1.0.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/johndevs/maven/fi/jasoft/plugin/gradle-vaadin-plugin/1.0.1/gradle-vaadin-plugin-1.0.1.jar'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

I tried to do a > build gradle and got the error. I have also tried importing a cache on a teammate that has it working but it does not recognize the cache I have imported by replacing my ~/.gradle with my teammates files

Comment: It doesn't look like you've used [the correct Maven coordinates](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin/1.0.1). Can you try with `classpath("fi.jasoft.plugin:gradle-vaadin-plugin:1.0.1")`?

Comment: Check with your coworker if the file is under `~/.m2/repository/fi/jasoft/plugin/gradle-vaadin-plugin` and copy it to this location. Maybe you will have to add `mavenLocal()` to the `repositories` section. Also why is it trying to load it from `http://dl.bintray.com/johndevs` - have you added this repository somewhere else?

Comment: @aSemy seems like if you follow the trail the maven link is not actual there for that version.

Comment: @cfrick it's the maven repo - it redirects to that link for that version. I ended up fixing it by going through the online website and finding one with an actual jar at the end of the repo links. classpath("fi.jasoft.plugin:gradle-vaadin-plugin:1.1.1") is there and works with my code

Comment: @NoahTaylor Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not actually there". If I look in the Gradle Plugins Maven repo I can see [version 1.0.1](https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/fi/jasoft/plugin/gradle-vaadin-plugin/1.0.1/).

Comment: @aSemy Thanks! for some reason gradle was looking here: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/fi/jasoft/plugin/vaadin/fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin.gradle.plugin/1.0.1/ but your link is showing the jars. thanks for finding it!

Comment: @aSemy if you post a response i'll mark yours as the answer cause I was having trouble finding that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've added a dependency on the wrong Maven coordinates.

Looking in the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin/1.0.1#groovy-usage) I can see that the dependency should be `classpath("fi.jasoft.plugin:gradle-vaadin-plugin:1.0.1")`

```groovy
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    // wrong coordinates:
    // classpath('fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin:fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin.gradle.plugin:1.0.1') 
    // correct coordinates:
    classpath("fi.jasoft.plugin:gradle-vaadin-plugin:1.0.1")
  }
}
```

The coordinates you had used, `fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin:fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin.gradle.plugin:1.0.1`, [do actually exist in the Gradle Plugin Portal Maven repo](https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/fi/jasoft/plugin/vaadin/fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin.gradle.plugin/1.0.1/), but there's no JAR. Why is this?

The reason for this is that Gradle plugins require a [marker artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers), so that Gradle can identify plugins using an ID [in the plugins block DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block).

For this reason, I recommend you replace using the `buildscript {}` block to define plugins, and instead use the new `plugins {}` block.

```groovy
plugins {
  id "fi.jasoft.plugin.vaadin" version "1.0.1"
}
```